# matrix problem: evaluation of column values which depend on a variable

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, procedural-programming

I do not use Mathematica for a long time and I have a question about a matrix problem.

I add here the code:

```
\[Omega] = 2 \[Pi]*f;
v = Sqrt[c/r];
c = Subscript[c,0] + I*\[Omega]*n1];
k1 = \[Omega]*Sqrt[r1/c];
k2 = \[Omega]*Sqrt[r2/m]]; 

y = ({{x1},{x2},{x3},{x4},{x5},{x6}});
amat = ({{e/[\[CurlyEpsilon]], e/[\[CurlyEpsilon]], 0, 0, 0, 1},
{e/[\[CurlyEpsilon]]*E^(I*k1*h1),e/[\[CurlyEpsilon]]*E^(-I*k1*h1), 0, 0, h1,1},{I*c*k1, -I*c*k1, 0, 0, e, 0},{I*c*k1*(E^(I*h1*k1)) , -I*c*k1*(E^(-I*h1*k1)), -I*k2*m*(E^(I*h1*k2)) , I*k2*m*(E^(-I*h1*k2)) , e, 0},
{E^(I*h1*k1), E^(-I*h1*k1), -E^(I* h1*k2), E^(-I* h1*k2), 0, 0},
{0, 0, E^(I*k2*(h1+h2)),-E^(-I*k2*(h1+h2)),0,0}});

bmat = ( {{\[CurlyPhi]},{-[\[CurlyPhi]},{0},{0},{0},{0}});

Solve[amat.y == bmat, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6}]
```

This is what I tried so far.
So, for a specific value of frequency, I can take the results for column y (x1,x2,x3,x4,x5, and x6), but I want to get at the same time the results for a range of frequencies (f goes from fmin to fmax). What is the best way to do that?

P.S. When I'll get the list of the values for the y column, can I isolate the results of one of them (i.e, x2) and calculate something else with that?

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Pasting the code that you have tried out so far establishes a reference point for the respondents. I recommend that you include your code and explain where you got stuck to get effective responses.

Comment: How clumsy of me! I forgot to say "Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange".

Comment: @Syed hello, Syed and thanks a lot. I edit my post and added the code.

Comment: Please use lowercase letters; I switched `amat` for `A` and `bmat` for `B`.  Then: `sol = Solve[amat . y == bmat, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6}];` gets these solutions into a list. In order to get individual items: e.g.,  `x1 /. sol /. {f -> fmin, Subscript[h, q] -> 3}` etc. Another note: avoid subscripts if possible.

Comment: `y = {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6}` would work as it is considered a vector in Mma.

Comment: @Syed Dear Syed. Thanks a lot for helping me. I did some changes now in my post. I did not write this in "coding mode" on my notebook so when I copy and paste it here it came like this. sorry for that. I will try what you suggest to me and start writing my code again. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Syed Dear Syed, it works like this for an individual item (i.e. fmin). What if I want to run it at the same time for a range of frequencies? from fmin to fmax? (i.e, from fmin=1MHz to fmax=10Mhz) can I use loop functions to do that?

Comment: With all other parameters specified as rules (i show only one), you can use a table command:  `t2 = Table[
  x1 /. sol /. {f -> fi, Subscript[h, q] -> 3}, {fi, 10^6, 10^7, 
   10^6}]` gives you 10 values from 1M to 10M. `t2 // Dimensions` ; If you want to plot it, you can specify all other values except the frequency and plot the resulting variable from from 1M to 10M on a `LogPlot`.